# how to apply filter blur on line tool? action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drawing

So i have two line tool. first is a normal line tool and second is line tool with filter blur effect. the tool work when the line draw on the canvas, but the first normal line tool also have a blur effect. How do i apply the blur effect on the second tool only?

sorry for bad grammar...

```
 var blurX:Number = 20;
 var blurY:Number = 20;
 var quality:Number = 1;
 var my_blur_filter:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(blurX, blurY, quality);
```

//tool without filter blur

```
function PencilTool(event:MouseEvent):void{

quitActiveTool();
active = "Pencil";

board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDown);
board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);

}


function MouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void{


    doDraw=true;

    drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(drawingLine.mouseX, drawingLine.mouseY);
    drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize, activeColor, lineAlpha);

    board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);

}
```

//tool with filter blur

```
 function brushTool(event:MouseEvent):void{

    quitActiveTool();
    active = "Brush";

      board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, brushMouseDown);
      board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);

}


function brushMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void{




    doDraw=true;

    if(active=="Brush"){
    drawingLine.filters = new Array(my_blur_filter);


    drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(drawingLine.mouseX, drawingLine.mouseY);


    drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize, activeColor, lineAlpha);


    }
    board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);

}
```

//mouse move & mouse up

```
function MouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void{
                var curX:Number=drawingLine.mouseX;
                var curY:Number=drawingLine.mouseY;


                        drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(curX,curY);


                    e.updateAfterEvent();

    }

function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void{

    doDraw=false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filters are applied to the whole display object, not just to graphics added after you set them. You could use two layers, `drawingLine` for the pencil and `drawingLineBlurred` for the brush, then only add the blur to `drawingLineBlurred`.

You can get more complicated by creating a new display object for every stroke, or even drawing those to a `BitmapData` object, but for a simple drawing tool this might be enough.

As an example of drawing multiple layers, you could make a new [`Shape`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html) every time the mouse is pressed down and draw to that instead of `drawingLine`:

```
private var currentStroke:Shape;

private function startDrawing():void {
    currentStroke = new Shape();
    addChild(currentStroke);

    // Apply the blur filter to currentStroke here if the brush tool is selected.

    currentStroke.graphics.moveTo(currentStroke.mouseX, currentStroke.mouseY);
    currentStroke.graphics.lineStyle(lineSize, activeColor, lineAlpha);
}

// etc
```

That's obviously not very efficient though, because you end up with lots and lots of `Shape`s. If it becomes a problem I would recommend looking at [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) instead and using that to draw to after each stroke is done.

Comment: we it work, but it put the line without blur at the back and the line with blur at the top. so how do i apply the current tool line that i select at the top and the previous line at the back?

Comment: You'll have to get a bit more complicated in that case, I've added an example of making a new layer for every stroke.